# Is there a web-based R API that would allow calling different methods from a web-based app?

Tags: r, statistics, maps

I'm working on a web-based app (haven't started coding yet actually, just the UML part). The purpose of the app is to provide certain maps (heat maps for instance), charts, plots, histograms, etc. All those graphs should be generated using a powerful statistical tool (such as R). I've been thinking about D3JS, but I have to deal with points, lines and every single little thing. It's a lot easier in R. Anyway, I just want to know if there's a way to call R (execute R code) from a web-based environment (which I haven't chosen yet).

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851208/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deploy-an-api-incorporating-r-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what language you use for the front end and what the rest of the site will be like.  For example, there are [rinruby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/), [rsruby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby) and [rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve/) that can be used in rails applications (an example is my site [StudyDesignCalculators.com](http://www.studydesigncalculators.com)).  [rpy](https://github.com/Sleepingwell/DjangoRpyDemo) can be used with Django.

[Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/) is good if you want everything to be in R, but for large websites, it is probable not optimal.  Rserve is nice because you can use it with many front end languages.