# Downloading Excel file from changing URL

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a scrip that downloads a file from the first link of this set of links [here](https://www.clevelandfed.org/en/Our%20Research/Indicators%20and%20Data/Datasets.aspx) "Cleveland Fed Estimates of Inflation Expectations" from the download icon.

I know how to get a file with a permanent url, but in this case the file will be updated regularly and the URL as well as the file name changes frequently.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: This isn't necessarily an R problem. I would just use another scripting language with better support for web scraping (e.g., Python + BeautifulSoup or PyQuery).

Comment: @alexpmil you may want to double-check your facts. R excels at web scraping. `httr`, `rvest`, `xml2`, `XML`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Great to know. That hasn't always been the case. I suppose the best answer would be "use whichever language you are most comfortable web scraping with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my area, but I'd suggest you build an API or something similar, to start, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851208/whats-the-easiest-way-to-deploy-an-api-incorporating-r-functions), [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/my-little-presentation-on-getting-web-data-through-r/) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html).

You'd need to get a [key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) from the F(R)ED. Not sure whether the Cleveland one has something like this, but St. Louis certainly [does](https://api.stlouisfed.org/docs/fred/).

Take a look at [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/), as well, it is available as a `package` from CRAN, another option is [FredR](http://www.jankocizel.com/FredR/), which you would need to get from Github.

Comment: Thank you. I am working with quantmod. On a realated note, could you do me a favor and check if this will work for you. It has been giving me an error all morning and worked fine yesterday.         `library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GDPC1",src="FRED")`

Comment: `Error in download.file(paste(FRED.URL, "/", Symbols[[i]], "/", "downloaddata/",  :
  cannot open URL 'http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/GDPC1/downloaddata/GDPC1.csv'` (but that URL works fine when I paste into a browser)